# #+CONSTANTS in Source Code Blocks

Tags: org-mode

The Org Manual is very clear about how to use constants defined using constructs such as `#+CONSTANTS: MYCONSTANT = 10` in table formulas. However, it is unclear if these global constants can be used in source code blocks.

Here is an example of how to use constants in table formulas.

```
#+CONSTANTS: t=2
|-----+--------|
| Val | Result |
|-----+--------|
|   1 |      2 |
|   2 |      4 |
|-----+--------|
#+TBLFM: @2$2=@2$1 * $t
#+TBLFM: @3$2=@3$1 * $t
```

Notice that you must prepend `$` to the variable name to make it accessible in formulas.

Is there any way to use constants defined using `#+CONSTANTS` in source code blocks.  I am aware of how to use `:session` to accomplish this with normal variables from one source code block in another. I am not interested in that.

Comment: AFAIK the answer is "no".

Comment: Appreciate the prompt answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not directly possible, but you can do something like this:

```
#+CONSTANTS: t=2

#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :var constants=(cadar (org-collect-keywords '("CONSTANTS")))
exec(constants)
print(t * 2)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 4
```

If the src block language doesn't support assignment in this way, you would have to do some additional parsing perhaps like this(here I changed the name to tee because t is a reserved keyword in emacs-lisp). Maybe there is a clever way to know when the value of tee is a number or string, I just assume number here.

#+CONSTANTS: tee=2

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var constants=(cadar (org-collect-keywords '("CONSTANTS")))
(let* ((parts (split-string constants "=")))
  (eval `(setq ,(intern-soft (first parts)) ,(string-to-number (second parts))))
  (* tee 2))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access properties in code blocks:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:foo: 42
:END:
```

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :var foo=(org-macro--get-property "foo" "")
echo $foo
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also this mind-bendingly awful trick:

```
#+property: header-args+ :var routers="rm284 rm288 rm332 rm336"

#+begin_src bash                                                                                                   
echo $routers                                                                                                      
#+end_src                                                                                                          

#+RESULTS[bf71...]:
: rm284 rm288 rm332 rm336
```

This way all blocks in the buffer will get the header :var added to it. You can even add more variables without overwriting the last one:

```
 #+property: header-args+ :var routers="rm284 rm288 rm332 rm336"
 #+property: header-args+ :var horses="neigh"

 #+begin_src bash
 echo $routers
 echo $horses
 #+end_src

 #+RESULTS[88286bf821889c3f3c2eb980b4afdc23b598f248]:
 : rm284 rm288 rm332 rm336
 : neigh
```